# OFX commands for retrieving pending transactions?

Tags: ofx

I am using an OFX download function written in Python similar to ofxclient to download bank and credit card transactions. However, it only retreives posted transactions, not ones that are in progress.  This results in the account infomation frequently being out of date by a day or more. I realize these pending transactions could be temporary (holds, etc.) But most of the time they turn into permanent transactions after they post or drop.  But is there some different OFX command I can use to request pending transactions, with the understanding that they are subject to change? It is possible to see them from the web site of every financial institution I have tried, but trying to scrape web sites is out of the question and OFX I though was designed to avoid the need for such non-standard procecures.

Comment: ever find an answer to retrieving pending transactions?

Comment: @JonBest no, unfortunately

Comment: me either. i'm looking into http://developer.yodlee.com/ . word on the street is it will grab pending as well because they use some sort of scrape technique.

Comment: @JonB Yeah, seems like that may be the only solution.  It's a shame too, especially since a lot of financial sites decide to periodically update their site or do stuff that risks breaking a scraper.   A *lot* of work just to keep it working, not ideal for an automated, set and forget solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `<INCLUDEPENDING>` flag; see [OFX Spec 2.2 - 2017](http://www.ofx.net/downloads/OFX%202.2.pdf), page 207.

It defaults to N. So, try:

`<INCLUDEPENDING>Y`

Note: The backend server must support this feature, which is available with OFX 2.2 (VERSION:220).